# Identifying a specific LED

Tags: led

Is there an easy way to identify exactly which LED I have? (So I can buy more that match in brightness).

I don't see any markings. Easiest thing I could think of is to measure the IV curve, but I'm not sure that will give me enough info to narrow it down. I don't have a way of measuring brightness, but maybe that would give me enough info to get something close enough...

Comment: No, there is no way to identify *exactly* .

Comment: No, Apart from the electrical characteristic there are the optics. e.g. the angle over which the light is radiated.

Comment: you'd have to measure radiation angle and brightness, and then you'd have to order from the maker,  places that retail LEDS will sell you a bunch that are closely matched in brightness, but the next bunch of the same part number may be different.

Comment: No, and even different batches of LEDs will vary (often they're marked by 'bin' number so you can match within a given assembly). Easiest is to buy some and compare unless you have a **large** budget for calibrated optical test equipment.

Comment: If you want matching LEDs, it would be easier to remove the one you got and use a matching set of known LEDs...